# Como posicionar um texto inclinadamente no ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

Existe um jeito de inclinar uma palavra (textbox, ou outra forma possível), no ReportViewer, de forma a ficar em 45º (graus), por exemplo?

Comment: 45 graus não sei, mas achei isso: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633659.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma forma um tanto bruta. Você pode usar as bibliotecas gráficas do framework para inserir o texto no relatório como imagem.

Você começa obtendo um objeto da classe [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics(v=vs.110).aspx). Existem várias formas... A partir do método [`Control.CreateGraphic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics(v=vs.110).aspx), a partir [de uma imagem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx), ou como propriedade que você recebe em um método que trate o evento [`Control.Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx).

Vamos suport um objeto gráfico `g`, uma fonte `f` e um *brush* `b`. A fonte e o *brush* são parâmetros que vamos usar, você pode ver mais detalhes na documentação acima. Com esses objetos, fazemos algo assim:

```
g.RotateTransform(45);
/* Isso gira sua "tela de pintura" no objeto de gráfico.
 * A partir de agora, tudo que for inserido no gráfico
 * estará inclinado em 45°.
 */
g.DrawString("foo",f, b, 10, 10);
```

Um aviso: o próprio sistema de coordenadas do gráfico estará inclinado. Se algo sair fora da tela, reposicione o gráfico.

Boa sorte!